# Excel problem: Search a column for a match, then return the column next to it

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match

I guess I'm the computer guru at this small company so I was tasked with figuring this out in Excel. I have a column with 1500 numbers, and two additional columns with 50,000 numbers. I need to search the small column, and if it matches any number in one of the bigger columns, it needs to return the column next to it to row.

Another way of saying this: If Column A matches **anything** in Column C, then Column B needs to be return to the value in Column D that is next to the match in Column C. In the image Row C contains the 50,000 numbers.

[image: Table Sample]

So far I tried to use MATCH, INDEX, and IF statements, but I'm not even close to returning the correct value.

Comment: INDEX/MATCH, VLOOKUP, XLOOKUP would do this.  `=VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE)`

Comment: `Row C contains the 50,000 numbers` Do you mean `Column C` insted of `Row C`

Comment: @ScottCraner It's always VLOOKUP... Always forget that one. Thank you so much

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome I did mean column. Scott got me where I needed to be. Thank you guys.